Methods to measure the IR intensity light using the Spectrometer
I'm a undergraduate student. Our group of friends plan to measure the IR light source intensity. We have a idea to do this.
In a dark room we place a IR light source in opposite to that we place a spectrometer and measure the value. We have a couple of questions regarding this.

Is there any ideal distance to measure the IR intensity?

Is there any other method to measure the IR light intensity?



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
